# When signing into my Office 365 account on a computer, how can I prevent Microsoft Teams from getting installed?

Tags: windows, office365, microsoft-teams

I signed into my Office 365 account on a computer running Windows 10, and saw that soon after Microsoft Teams got installed:

[image]

When signing into my Office 365 account on a computer, how can I prevent Microsoft Teams from getting installed?

Comment: "Teams is installed as default now for new installations. See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/DeployOffice/teams-install for more info. As a workaround, you can choose to install version prior to 16.0.11328.20116", from https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/90ff3fa8-b94a-44fa-85a3-b1c3c47a0723/microsoft-teams-autoinstalling?forum=microsoftintuneprod

Comment: @DrMoishePippik thanks!

Comment: Try running "appwiz.cpl" and chek whether the Teams Machine Wide Installer has been installed on your machine.  If it has, uninstall it.  This is from https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmanager/microsoft-teams-keeps-reinstalling.html.  Note that this is only for W10 and below.  On W11, teams will automatically install because of the chat application, which replaces skype.

Comment: @cup thanks, yes I uninstalled it via `appwiz.cpl`. Good to know about Windows 11!

Comment: appwiz.cpl takes me to the list of programs installed on the computer from where I uninstall the Teams machine wide installer, but the next time I boot the computer, it gets added in there automatically and teams starts up again. Any poitners on how to fix this? @franck-dernoncourt

Comment: Any pointers @cup ?

Answer (score 3):

Another way is Business and Enterprise editions can exclude Teams installations using  [Office Customization Tool](https://config.office.com/deploymentsettings).
[image]

Comment: Thanks! "Microsoft 365 Apps for Entreprise".

Answer (score 0):

As [DrMoishe Pippik](https://superuser.com/users/401553/drmoishe-pippik) [mentioned](https://superuser.com/questions/1728418/when-signing-into-my-office-365-account-on-a-computer-how-can-i-prevent-microso#comment2671904_1728418) in the comment section:

1. Microsoft Teams is included with Office installations nowadays.
2. On [social.technet.microsoft.com](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/90ff3fa8-b94a-44fa-85a3-b1c3c47a0723/microsoft-teams-autoinstalling?forum=microsoftintuneprod) it sounds like Office 365 admins can disable the auto-install on Microsoft Intune:

   [image]